# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Зачем все так прекрасно ясно у меня в душе и так безобразно выходит на бумаге и вообще в жизни когда я хочу применять к ней что-нибудь из того что думаю.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем всё так прекрасно, ясно у меня в душе и так безобразно выходит на бумаге и вообще в жизни, когда я хочу применять к ней что-нибудь из того, что думаю.

Это СПП с последовательным подчинением, первое придаточное времени (союз КОГДА),  второе придаточное местоименно-определительное (указательное слово ИЗ ТОГО, союзное слово ЧТО).

Первое предложение осложнено однородными сказуемыми и дополнениями.

Союз И соединяет сказуемые: так (прекрасно, ясно) и так безобразно выходит.

Нет причин считать, что это два предложения. Сравнить: Зачем всё так ясно в душе и так безобразно в жизни.Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем (все так прекрасно, ясно у меня в душе) и (так безобразно выходит (на бумаге и вообще в жизни), (когда я хочу применять к ней (что-нибудь из того, (что думаю))))

-- частичный разбор на синтаксические группы/составляющие. Скобки показывают вложенность-синтаксич. зависимость

Comment: Ваша разбивка хороша для художественного чтения, выделенные смысловые группы можно обозначить изменением тембровой окраски голоса. А вообще, мудрая эта мысль у Толстого. Почему-то действительно всё тщательно продуманное и совершенное  реализуется в реальности с очень большой погрешностью.